# How to update multiple rows value in one query in particular column

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE job_seekers SET js_email = 
       CASE js_email 
              WHEN "Wbsirota@gmail.com" THEN "bsirota@gmail.com" 
              WHEN "@nautiyalanuj@gmail.com"THEN "nautiyalanuj@gmail.com" 
              WHEN ".agiletestanalyst​@gmail.com" THEN "agiletestanalyst​@gmail.com" 
       END ) WHERE js_email IN ("wbsirota@gmail.com", 
                                "@nautiyalanuj@gmail.com", 
                                ".agiletestanalyst​@gmail.com");
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Wbsirota@gmail.com  ====> bsirota@gmail.com this is i expected output

Comment: After looking into this question , I feel like he just want to remove the first character from value.

Comment: I think you're correct @AlpeshJikadra ! That would make the query much shorter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 UPDATE
   job_seekers
 SET
    js_email = CASE WHEN js_email = 'Wbsirota@gmail.com' THEN 
    'bsirota@gmail.com' WHEN js_email = '@nautiyalanuj@gmail.com' THEN 
    'nautiyalanuj@gmail.com' WHEN js_email = '.agiletestanalyst​ 
    @gmail.com' THEN 'agiletestanalyst​@gmail.com' ELSE js_email END
    WHERE
    js_email IN ("wbsirota@gmail.com","@nautiyalanuj@gmail.com",
    ".agiletestanalyst​@gmail.com");
```

EXAMPLE IS BELOW

```
   UPDATE
       dbo.TestStudents
   SET
       LASTNAME = CASE WHEN LASTNAME = 'AAA' THEN 'BBB'
       WHEN LASTNAME = 'CCC' THEN 'DDD' 
       WHEN LASTNAME = 'EEE' THEN 'FFF' ELSE LASTNAME END
       WHERE
       LASTNAME IN ('AAA', 'CCC', 'EEE');
```